# Magento 1.7 - onepage checkout hangs at billing information, no errors

Tags: ajax, magento, magento-1.7, checkout

I'm totally stumped on this - I'm hoping someone's expertise can provide the answer.

Going through the onepage checkout that comes with Magento's default theme, the process hangs on the billing information step. It displays the "processing" gif, but then just returns to the continue button like the form was invalidated.

Now here's the tricky part: magento reports zero errors. Firebug reports no javascript errors. I cleaned out `/var/report/` and emptied all the files in `/var/log/` before attempting it, and after triggering the problem two or three times `/var/report/` remains empty and `/var/log/` remains blank.

No javascript/ajax errors come up in firebug when it happens, no error reports get left behind - no indication that anything is wrong, except that it isn't working.

Does anyone know what's going on? Or does anyone know another trick for diagnosing this?

For anyone interested, the store is at http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/.

Comment: Update: found an old thread at http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/24844/. Both col-right and block-progress exist as classes in the checkout page, but none of the proposed fixes work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [R.S's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348720/1191288) feedback, I found out the problem was in the 1.7 version of /code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php.

Adding this to the bottom of the file (line 920) fixed it:

`public function _doShipmentRequest(Varien_Object $request){ }`

Hope this helps anyone with the same problem!

Answer (score 2):

This is your error

> Fatal error: Class Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Abstract::_doShipmentRequest) in /.../scss/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php on line 37

See [1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663905/1-abstract-method-and-must-therefore-be-declared-abstract-or-implement-the-remai)

Answer (score 0):

Identical problem but a different solution (adding CodeMoose's _DoShipmentRequest to the bottom line of Usps.php (line 1700 in my case) caused Magento to throw an error).

While looking to isolate the issue by disabling shipping options from the shipping config I encountered a strange "undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH" error in the admin upon saving the changes.

The root of this error was that php5-mcrypt was not installed. It had recently been flagged by Apt as no longer used and Apt continuously begged me to remove it with 'apt-get autoremove' :)

Upon reinstalling php5-mcrypt the problem disappeared and was again able to checkout as normal.